# Git combined diff over date range with added intelligence

Tags: git

I want to display a combined diff that shows:

1. Changes made by a specific person.
2. Changes made between a date range.
3. Diff excludes lines where the only change is a case change to one or more letters.
4. Diff excludes lines where the only change is a number changing.

I have managed to satisfy the first two requirements with the following:

```
git log --after="2015-01-01" --before="2016-01-01" --author="Dave" -p --all --unified=0 -w
```

However I am struggling to meet requirements 3 & 4.

Comment: What have you tried? It sounds like you need to write a little program to achieve that.

Comment: @blue112, I can get it to work for the person and the date range, but am struggling with the other two requirements.

Comment: Show us what you've done, and what you've tried with the rest.

Comment: @blue112 - I have updated my original question to address your requests. Thanks.